# sqlite3 variable substitution not working python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to get the SQLlite3 variable substitution in Python working, but I always get the error:
*sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.*

I've tried:

```
date_range = '10'

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_LOGIN) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    template = "SELECT DISTINCT date FROM schedule WHERE date BETWEEN DATETIME('NOW') AND DATETIME('NOW', '-? DAYS') ORDER BY date"
    cursor.execute(template, date_range)
```

and I know it's very bad form to use:

```
date_range = '10'

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_LOGIN) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        template = f"SELECT DISTINCT date FROM schedule WHERE date BETWEEN DATETIME('NOW') AND DATETIME('NOW', '-{date_range} DAYS') ORDER BY date"
        cursor.execute(template)
```

but for some reason the former query doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you change `-?` to `?`?

Comment: yes, I tried that when testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must concatenate the placeholder `?`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date 
FROM schedule 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATETIME('NOW') AND DATETIME('NOW', '-' || ? || ' DAY') ORDER BY date
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. Does it say in the documentation anywhere where this is necessary? What causes the normal substitution to not work here?

Comment: This: `'-? DAYS'` is a string literal and the `?` is not considered as a placeholder, this is why you get: *The current statement uses 0* which means that your statement does not contain any bindings. When `?` is not contained inside a string literal then it is considered as a placeholder and is substituted by the variable that you supply.